# does VNC Server reply the SetEncoding and SetPixelFormat message from Client?

Tags: vnc, rfb-protocol

I am trying to implement the VNC client.
when I send SetEncoding or SetPixelFormat, it seems the server will reply with something which I debug it using Wireshark. below is the reply after `SetPixelFormat`.
[image]
[image]

I referred to https://web.archive.org/web/20160410055332/http://www.realvnc.com/docs/rfbproto.pdf. but it doesn't mention the server reply, so what are the 60 bytes?